# Probability of WaveFunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability

> A particle is confined in a one dimensional box of length $a$.
>
> What is the probability of finding the particle at $x = a/4$?

I know that the wave function is written as

$$y= A\sin([(\pi x)/a]$$ where $x$ is from 0 to $a$.

After normalization, I found that
$$A = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}},$$
so $$y= \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{a}\right)$$

I know to find the probability of a region $(a,b)$ I need to integrate from $a$ to $b$ over the probability density. However I don't know how to find the probability at a specific point (i.e. $x=a/4$).

Comment: would the probability of a specific point equal to 0?

Comment: Yes, if the distribution function is assumed to be continuous. Which in this case it is...

Answer (score 2):

As with any continuous probability distribution, the probability of finding the particle at any specific point is equal to zero.

Luckily that's not a real problem, because the best any physical experiment can do is to find (or fail to find) the particle in some finite region of space.